# Why is python pocketsphinx giving TypeError?

Tags: python, pocketsphinx

I am using the Python pocket sphinx tutorial, according to

https://metakermit.com/2011/python-speech-recognition-helloworld/

(complete code here):

```
import sys,os

def decodeSpeech(hmmd,lmdir,dictp,wavfile):
"""
Decodes a speech file
"""

try:
    import pocketsphinx as ps
    import sphinxbase

except:
    print """Pocket sphinx and sphixbase is not installed
    in your system. Please install it with package manager.
    """

speechRec = ps.Decoder(hmm = hmmd, lm = lmdir, dict = dictp)
wavFile = file(wavfile,'rb')
wavFile.seek(44)
speechRec.decode_raw(wavFile)
result = speechRec.get_hyp()

return result[0]

if __name__ == "__main__":
hmdir = "/usr/share/pocketsphinx/model/hmm/en_US/"
lmd = "/usr/share/pocketsphinx/model/lm/en_US/hub4.5000.DMP"
dictd = "/usr/share/pocketsphinx/model/lm/en_US/cmu07a.dic"
wavfile = sys.argv[1]
recognised = decodeSpeech(hmdir,lmd,dictd,wavfile)

print "%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%"
print recognised
print "%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%"
```

and when I run it I get the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "hello.py", line 30, in <module>
recognised = decodeSpeech(hmdir,lmd,dictd,wavfile)
File "hello.py", line 17, in decodeSpeech
speechRec = ps.Decoder(hmm = hmmd, lm = lmdir, dict = dictp)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'hmm'
```

Could you help me?

Comment: check what argument you can past to the __init__

Comment: @galaxyan Edited. Sorry about identation.

Comment: I mean the error said you the hmm is not the argument you can pass in init

Comment: try to dir the class

Comment: Is this what you mean? python hello.py Voice_004.wav

Comment: ps.Decoder(hmm = hmmd, lm = lmdir, dict = dictp) has __init__ to initial the object. it can not have hmm as input argument

Comment: From what I can see in the [example file bundled with the project](https://github.com/cmusphinx/pocketsphinx-python/blob/master/example.py), the `Decoder()` class takes just one `config` argument. I suspect your tutorial is out of date, find a different tutorial.

Comment: I used the "new" example and I get `RuntimeError: new_Decoder returned -1

Comment: You need to use "new" example. Runtime error is caused by incorrect path to the model it seems, you can find additional details in the log

Comment: Should I change the path used in the code?

Comment: If you do `help(ps.Decoder)`, does it mention the arguments that it takes?  As Martijn Pieters said, it could be that your tutorial is for a different version.

Comment: Try passing in arguments in order without the keywords. `ps.Decoder(hmmd, lmdir, dictp)`

Answer (score 8):

Looking at the pocketsphinx code on GitHub, in [decoder_test.py](https://github.com/cmusphinx/pocketsphinx/blob/a1581355154206af5b33935e7dc180b6f7989265/swig/python/test/decoder_test.py) we have an example of how to pass options to Decoder.

So it looks like your tutorial is for an old version and you actually want:

```
config = ps.Decoder.default_config()
config.set_string('-hmm', hmmd)
config.set_string('-lm', lmdir)
config.set_string('-dict', dictp) 

speechRec = ps.Decoder(config)
```